# Can I move all my bin and user folders to another disk?

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using Fedora 17 (rpm based) and the root is mounted on a 20G SSD. I have another big HDD which I want to use for the bin folders and user / home.

Can I re-mount all the bin folders to that disk and only contains linux clean core in the SSD? What are all the folders I have to redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to redirect anything, mounting is completely transparent as far as the OS is concerned. Linux will just look for a `/usr` directory. If you have another partition mounted at `/usr` or if `/usr` is just a directory in your `/` partition makes absolutely no difference at all.

So, what you want to do is the following (as root, and assuming your partition is `sda2`):

1. Mount your empty partition to a temporary location:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda2 tmpdir
   ```
2. Copy your `/usr` folder to the new partition:

   ```
   cp -rv /usr tmpdir
   ```
3. Rename `/usr`

   ```
   mv /usr /usr.backup
   ```
4. Create a new `/usr` directory

   ```
   mkdir /usr
   ```
5. Unmount from the temp mountpoint and mount the partition to `/usr`

   ```
   umount /dev/sda2
   mount /dev/sda2 /usr
   ```
6. Edit `/etc/fstab` to make the change permanent, something like:

   ```
   /dev/sda2   /usr    ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0   1
   ```

---

If you want to have many, different system directories on this partition, you can use links:

1. Mount the partition somewhere (e.g. `/data`)
2. Copy the, for example, `/usr` and `/etc` folders to `/data`
3. Delete the `/usr` and `/etc` directories
4. Recreate them as links to `/data`

   ```
   ln -s /data/usr /usr
   ln -s /data/etc /etc
   ```

Comment: you'll need to be sure you still have, lcoally, everything you need during boot (ie, before those partition gets mounted. And by the way, they will be mounted by 'mount', which also should be there ^^). You could have a local trimmed-down bin, and /sbin, and /lib, etc, containing just "what you need", and those get overwritten later on during the boot process with the remote /bin, etc.

Comment: I want to see his face on the next boot when the first script tries to call /bin/mount ×eg×

Comment: I suggest **not** deleting the old folder. Just move it aside until you know everything works. (E.g. `mv /bin /bin.backup`)

Comment: Also, do not move /bin and /sbin. However you are free to move /usr/bin, /usr/sbin and (if they exist) /usr/local/[s]bin/

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry, I had originally written the answer thinking of the `/usr/bin` directory and then changed to `/bin` to make it "clearer" not realizing that I was recommending a good way to bork the system. Thanks @OlivierDulac and @ott for pointing it out.

Comment: Should I move /var too? Any other folder I should take care if they can expand?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just save space? In that case, usr, etc and to a lesser extent var are what you should move.

Comment: @terdon: You left out step 4½: `umount /dev/sda2`.  (Or it could be 2½ or 3½.)  Or does step 5 do that implicitly?

Comment: @hennes : do not move the /bin folder, no need: copy over to the new location, and then mount the new over the old (so that, when the new one isn't mounted, the old one still contain what's needed to operate. You can cleanup that one later, once sure what can be trimmed off (ie, everything not needed until the new one overlaps the old one)

Comment: @terdon : you also need several other stuff to be available at boot (/dev, /etc, /tmp, /lib, ..., or at least some of their content)

Comment: I tried moving /home (as its minimal damage) to the other disk but it refused to go into X environment... just stuck at the screen before login. I recovered and may try symbolic link method later.

Comment: @texasbruce then you are probably not mounting the new `/home` correctly, there should be no problems when moving `/home`.

Comment: @OlivierDulac I am not sure you're right. Most of the directories you listed are accessed _after_ the disks have been mounted. In any case, I am actually not sure that _any_ directory is absolutely necessary since I know that `/boot` can be on a separate partition and that `/` itself needs to be mounted. If these can be mounted correctly I would guess (though I don't know) that most if not all partitions are mounted early enough to make no difference. Or maybe `/` and `/boot` are special cases?

Comment: @terdon: [wikipedia page about linux boot process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) : see how quite a lof of operation (optionnally mount an initrd, mount root filesystem ro, etc) occur before the "Init" phase in which the other filesystem are mounted. I'm sure there are pages out there telling what you need to have to boot properly before that (quite advanced) phase occurs.

Comment: @OlivierDulac, yeah, all I'm saying is that I don't really know :). However, it does seem that mounting does not depend on `/bin/mount` since that command is unavailable before `/` is mounted, catch22...

Comment: root fs is mounted by the kernel, see the link above ^^. But then, quite a bit after, when finally "init" start to read its starting files (Of course, on some recent systems you don't have "init" at all, but it's replace by another things. Even then there is still things occuring before you can mount the other-than-root-and-ramdisk fs, and you need some commands to do some of them, and some files such as a /dev/null facility, and /tmp directory, etc, some mandatory, other avoiding lots of errors and warnings and head scratching)