# how can i move my usr folder to my HDD.i have installed UBUNTU 14.04 in my SSD and have also moved my home folder to my HHD

Tags: hard-drive, installation, ssd

please help me to move my usr folder because my SSD doesnt have a lot of space and i want install the programmes in my SSD.i have moved my home folder to my Hdd and i want more space for my programmes.I have read this article in the same  site but i would like to have something more up to date and sure. [Can I move all my bin and user folders to another disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/529433/can-i-move-all-my-bin-and-user-folders-to-another-disk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I move all my bin and user folders to another disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/529433/can-i-move-all-my-bin-and-user-folders-to-another-disk)

Answer (score 0):

I found this article very helpful if you have an LVM filesystem:
https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk/
Just skip the the VM part if that's not relevant for you. It basically shows you how to add a new disk, a new partition and make it part of an existing partition.